# Terraform : for_each one by one

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform-template-file

I have created a module on terraform, this module creates `aws_servicecatalog_provisioned_product` resources.
When I call this module from the root I am using for_each to run into a list of objects.
The module runs into this list of objects and creates the `aws_servicecatalog_provisioned_product` resources in parallel.
Is there a way to create the resources one by one? I want that the module will wait for the first iteration to be done and to create the next just after.

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear how what you can do?

Comment: I am using jinja template which creates multiple resources with depons_on to the previous resource.

Comment: @DaniWol.- Could You share a solution - I am currently tackling similiar case

Comment: @MichałDygas I am using terraform `templatefile` that creates resources with a `depends on` order, and then terraform creates resources one by one.

Comment: @DaniWol. I understand the concept, but frankly speaking I am curious about the implementation details. I have tried approach, that was generating local file, during initial apply. During second apply resources were created. Unfortunately it's a tideous aproach - mainly lacking the automation part. So may I again ask You to share a snippet?

Comment: I just posted the solution I am using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am using terraform `templatefile` that creates resources with a `depends on` order, and then terraform creates resources one by one.

Here is the code:

```
locals {

     expanded_accounts = [ 
      {
          AccountEmail                           = example1@example.com
          AccountName                         = example1
          ManagedOrganizationalUnit           = example_ou1
          SSOUserEmail                        = example1@example.com
          SSOUserFirstName                    = Daniel
          SSOUserLastName                     = Wor
          ou_id                               = ou_id1
      },
      {
          AccountEmail                           = example2@example.com
          AccountName                         = example2
          ManagedOrganizationalUnit           = example_ou2
          SSOUserEmail                        = example2@example.com
          SSOUserFirstName                    = Ben
          SSOUserLastName                     = John
          ou_id                               = ou_id2
     }
     ]

  previous_resource = [
    for acc in local.expanded_accounts :
    acc.AccountName
  ]

     resources = { res = local.expanded_accounts, previous = concat([""], local.previous_resource)
}

resource "local_file" "this" {
  content              = templatefile("./provisioned_accounts.tpl", local.resources)
  filename             = "./generated_provisioned_accounts.tf"
  directory_permission = "0777"
  file_permission      = "0777"

  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [directory_permission, file_permission, filename]
  }
}
```

`provisioned_accounts.tpl` configuration:

```
%{ for acc in res }
resource "aws_servicecatalog_provisioned_product" "${acc.AccountName}" {
  name                     = "${acc.AccountName}"
  product_id               = replace(data.local_file.product_name.content, "\n", "")
  provisioning_artifact_id = replace(data.local_file.pa_name.content, "\n", "")
  

  provisioning_parameters {
    key   = "SSOUserEmail"
    value = "${acc.SSOUserEmail}"
  }
  provisioning_parameters {
    key   = "AccountEmail"
    value = "${acc.AccountEmail}"
  }
  provisioning_parameters {
    key   = "AccountName"
    value = "${acc.AccountName}"
  }
  provisioning_parameters {
    key   = "ManagedOrganizationalUnit"
    value = "${acc.ManagedOrganizationalUnit} (${acc.ou_id})"
  }
  provisioning_parameters {
    key   = "SSOUserLastName"
    value = "${acc.SSOUserLastName}"
  }
  provisioning_parameters {
    key   = "SSOUserFirstName"
    value = "${acc.SSOUserFirstName}"
  }

  timeouts {
    create = "60m"
  }

%{if index != 0 }
  depends_on = [aws_servicecatalog_provisioned_product.${previous[index]}]
%{ endif }

}

%{~ endfor ~}
```

Comment: I tried your approach and it generates the .tf file as it should. Is there an option to invoke the file in scope of the ongoing terraform run in which the file was created? Can you recommend any other approach?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to create the resources one by one?

Sadly, there is not such way, unless you remove `for_each` and create all the modules separately with `depends_on`.

TF is not a procedural language, and it always will do things in parallel for `for_each` and `count`.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want it to wait for the previous creation? Terraform relies on the provider to know what can happen in parallel and will run in parallel where it can.

Setting the parallelism before the apply operation would be how I would limit it artificiality if I wanted to as it's an technical workaround that keeps your Terraform code simple to read.

```
TF_CLI_ARGS_apply="-parallelism=1"
terraform apply
```

If you find this is slowing down all Terraform creations but you need this particular set of resources to be deployed one at a time then it might be time to break these particular resources out into their own Terraform config directory and apply it in a different step to the rest of the resources again with the parallelism setting.

Comment: when I am creating the `aws_servicecatalog_provisioned_product` one of the resources is created successfully and the other gets the following error: `ResourceInUseException Account Factory cannot create this enrolled account right now, because another execution is in progress. Try again later.`
also when I create the resource from the console I get the same error, parallelism will affect all the resources and it's not good for me.

Comment: Sounds like a bug in the provider, @DaniWol.

Comment: @DaniWol, My suggestion again would be to split the directory for this resource. Or alternatively you could raise the issue on the provider Github page and even contribute a fix.

Here's an example where someone did this for the same issue with EKS Fargate.
Issue raised: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/13372
Contribution: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/pull/14020

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the `for_each` and use `depends_on` for every element if you want to make sure that they are created one after another.

If you want only the first resource to be provisioned before other resources:

Separate the first resource only and use the `for_each` for the remaining resources. You can put an explicit dependency using `depends_on` for the remaining resources to depend on the first one. Because `for_each` expects a `set` or a `map`, this input would require some modification to be able to exclude the provisioning of the first resource.

A more drastic approach, if you really need to provision resources one by one, would be to run the `apply` command with `-parallelism=1`. This would reduce the number of resources provisioned in parallel to 1. This would apply to the whole project. I would not recommend this, since it would increase drastically the running time for the apply.

Comment: parallelism will affect all the resources and it's not good for me.
I need to provision resources one by one but not to apply the parallelism to all resources.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the approach given by @Rafał Radecki but it gives me below error:
Error: Invalid function argument
on test_sequential_loop.tf line 42, in resource "local_file" "this":
42:   content              = templatefile("./test.tpl",local.resources)
while calling templatefile(path, vars)
local.resources is object with 2 attributes
Invalid value for "vars" parameter: vars map does not contain key "index", referenced at ./test.tpl:37,6-11.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34509762)